# Nodejs append backend data to html

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nodemailer

I am using the html as content and sending the mail, but one more requirement is need to get  the data from backend and need to append to  the html.I am getting error of syntax at the path can anyone help me

```
 client.query(query, function(err, result1) {
   var renderTemplate = function('/index2.html', result1.rows) {
     fs.readFile('/index2.html', 'utf8', function(err, file){
      return ejs.render('/index2.html', result1.rows); }} });
```

Comment: What data do you need to get from the backend?

Comment: I am getting the name,email_id of the person and storing the records in result1 , now need to append the result1 to html

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: I realize that ejs v1 may not be as popular, so this was edited to work with v2.

This example uses ejs, **be sure to install ejs** for this example to work.

I didn't write any error handling, be sure to write the error handling if this is for production.

Rendering a template with inserted data:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var renderTemplate = function(pathToHtmlTemplate, dataToBeInserted) {

    // reads your template file to be used in the callback
    fs.readFile(pathToHtmlTemplate, 'utf8', function(err, file) {

        // returns a rendered html with data to driver code
        return ejs.render(pathToHtmlTemplate, dataToBeInserted);

    }
}
```

Your html template should use something like <%= data.name %> :

```
<ul>
    <li><%=data.name%></li>
    <li><%=data.email%></li>
</ul>
```

Further information about the library: https://github.com/mde/ejs

Comment: Getting the syntax error at the second loop closing .

Comment: @SaiKishore Interesting, copy and paste the error logs into your original post. Also an update on what your code looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML file is prepared to have data *appended* to it then you can use fs.append like this:

```
fs.appendFile(pathToFile, dataToAppend, function(err) {
    if (err) // Handle error
    transporter.sendMail({
        from : xxxx@gmail.com,
        to : xxxx@gmail.com,
        subject : 'Invitation',
        html : pathToFile
    })
})
```

But if you have closing tags that may cause issues...

Comment: Getting an error Unexpected token ILLEGAL at the '@' place

Comment: Are the email addresses strings? They should be surrounded in `' '`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some library like nunjucks(https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#renderstring)
var res = nunjucks.render('foo.html', { username: 'James' });
Should give you the html you want.

I didn't try but it should work.